# Simplistic tab navigation that works on many browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I'm looking for a way to have tabs on my webpage.

Unfortunately, a lot of them either use Javascript, JQuery, or advanced CSS that may not be present on older browsers (or enabled on newer browsers)

It's a simple matter of clicking a piece of text and having some text shown, or clicking another piece of text and having different textual data shown.

Is such a thing possible or will I have to use either advanced HTML5/CSS or Javascript/JQuery to accomplish such a thing?

Comment: If by "tabs" you mean a visual representation of horizontal links styled in a "tabular" design, then yes, you need at least CSS.

Comment: You can create a dropdown navigation with tabs using the :hover state in CSS, however, if you require clicks, you'll need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used some JQuery because they said it was okay.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out Twitter Bootstrap? They have a simple to use tab thingy: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

It involves some Javascript but I think it's pretty simple to use it.